# Pycharm on Raspbian NO JDK found

Tags: raspberry-pi, installation, pycharm

i was trying to install Pycharm on my Rasberry PI and as i typed "./pycharm.sh" in the Terminal to install it, i get this error:

No JDK found.Please validate eiter PYCHARM_JDK,JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

I followed this Tutorial for the Install
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAjwzkEDrgI

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Did you check system requirements for PyCharm? they are: 2 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended. I hope you are not going to use your SD card for swap...

Comment: The Raspberry Pi hast 4GB RAM and i dont use the SD-Card for swap

Comment: What PyCharm version are you trying to run?

Answer (score 3):

Install a valid JDK. You may use:

````sh
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk```  
It worked for me.
````